# What is the difference between "his head was drooping as he was falling asleep" and "his head was flopping as he was falling asleep"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

These from the dictionary

> [droop](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/droop_1?q=droop) ​[intransitive] to bend, hang or move downwards, especially
> because of being weak or tired
>
> the drooping branches of the apple tree
>
> She was so tired, her eyelids were beginning to droop.
>
> The plants were drooping from lack of water.

> [flop](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/flop_1?q=flop) [intransitive] + adv./prep. to fall, move or hang in a heavy way,
> without control
>
> Her hair flopped over her eyes.
>
> The fish were flopping around in the bottom of the boat.

It seems like "**to droop**" means to hang because of being tired or weak

and "**to flop**" means to hang because of heaviness

What is the difference between "**his head was drooping as he was falling asleep**" and "**his head was flopping as he was falling asleep**"?

Comment: _Droop_ is more appropriate. I would not describe a person's head as flopping unless they were completely unconscious or severely disabled.

Comment: If someone's head is flopping that suggests that their neck is broken, and they may be dead.

Comment: To me, *flopping* suggests moving around actively, not just hanging.